# ELan touchpad not detected

Tags: updates, touchpad, kernel

After updating Kali Linux too kernel 5.4 . my touch pad is not detected . 
my kernel is:

```
Linux sorush 5.4.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.8-1kali1 (2020-01-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ic2_h cannot detect my touchpad

```
journalctl  | grep -Ei "elan|i2c_hid":

Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c-ELAN1200:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c-ELAN1200:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: failed to reset device.
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: failed to reset device.
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: failed to reset device.
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: failed to reset device.
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: can't add hid device: -61
Jan 22 18:00:44 sorush kernel: i2c_hid: probe of i2c-ELAN1200:00 failed with error -61
```

niether

```
xinput list
```

nor

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices
```

shows my toucpad

Comment: __less /proc/bus/input/devices__ do you see a touchpad anywhere in that list? Please visit this page, like SuperUser, AskUbuntu is part of StackExchange https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working (Typing __xinput__ will show if the X server has detected your touchpad....

Comment: Although that info may be useful, http://Askubuntu.com is not a good place to find Kali support because of differences between the distros. See http://kali.org/blog and http://forums.kali.org and if neither answer your questions, the Kali IRC channel is #kali-linux, and can be found on irc.freenode.net. There's also  http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: i checked and xinput dosent show my touchpad

Comment: any idea,  this happened after update . i have this problem on Manjaro i think its from kernel.